# Eta-equality for records: the case of semigroups

Tags: coq, equality, eta-equality

Consider the following definition of a semigroup:

```
Set Primitive Projections.

Record SG (A : Type) : Type := {
 oper: A -> A -> A;
 assoc :     forall x y z, oper x (oper y z) = oper (oper x y) z;
 assoc_sym : forall x y z, oper (oper z y) x = oper z (oper y x)
}.
```

The field `assoc_sym` may appear useless because it is a trivial consequence of the field `assoc`. But it allows to define the `opposite` semigroup in such a way that `opposite (opposite sg)` and `sg` are definitionally equal.

```
Definition opposite [A : Type] (sg : SG A) : SG A := {|
 oper := fun x y => oper A sg y x;
 assoc := fun x y z => assoc_sym A sg x y z;
 assoc_sym := fun x y z => assoc A sg x y z
|}.

Lemma involutive : forall A (sg : SG A), opposite (opposite sg) = sg.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

However in definitions of semigroups other than the `opposite` we would like Coq to automatically fill the field `assoc_sym` because we do not care about the chosen proof term. This can be done by providing a generic proof term for `assoc_sym` in the definition of `SG`:

```
Record SG (A : Type) : Type := {
 oper: A -> A -> A;
 assoc :     forall x y z, oper (oper x y) z = oper x (oper y z);
 assoc_sym : forall x y z, oper z (oper y x) = oper (oper z y) x :=
  fun x y z => eq_sym (assoc z y x)
}.
```

Then we can define the following semigroup without having to fill the `assoc_sym` field:

```
Definition trv : SG nat := {|
 oper := fun x y => x + y;
 assoc := Nat.add_assoc
|}.
```

Unfortunately, the generic proof term in `SG` makes the `involutive` equality not definitional and Coq does not allow the user to give an explicit proof term for `assoc_sym` because we have provided a generic one in `SG`:

```
Definition opposite [A : Type] (sg : SG A) : SG A := {|
 oper := fun x y => oper A sg y x;
 assoc := fun x y z => assoc_sym A sg x y z
|}.

Lemma involutive : forall A (sg : SG A), opposite (opposite sg) = sg.
Proof. Fail reflexivity. Abort.
```

**Questions**: Is there a way to tell Coq that I do not want to use the generic proof term in the definition of `opposite`? If this feature is not available, is there a generic proof term that would allow the `involutive` equality proof to be definitional?

The first thing I tried was to redefine `eq_sym` because it is opaque in the standard library.

```
Definition eq_sym [A : Type] [x y : A] (p : x = y) : y = x :=
match p in (_ = y) return (y = x) with eq_refl => eq_refl end.
```

But it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to do things the other way around: define `SG` with all the fields, without any one of them being defined. Then define an interface that will automatically fill in the fields that can be defined.

```
Require Import Nat Arith.

Set Primitive Projections.

Record SG (A : Type) : Type := {
 oper: A -> A -> A;
 assoc :     forall x y z, oper x (oper y z) = oper (oper x y) z;
 assoc_sym : forall x y z, oper (oper z y) x = oper z (oper y x)
}.

Definition opposite [A : Type] (sg : SG A) : SG A := {|
 oper := fun x y => oper A sg y x;
 assoc := fun x y z => assoc_sym A sg x y z;
 assoc_sym := fun x y z => assoc A sg x y z
|}.

Lemma involutive : forall A (sg : SG A), opposite (opposite sg) = sg.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.

Definition SG_builder
  {A : Type}
  (oper : A -> A -> A)
  (assoc : forall x y z, oper x (oper y z) = oper (oper x y) z) :
  SG A.
Proof.
  econstructor.
  - eassumption.
  - now symmetry.
Defined.

Definition trv : SG nat := SG_builder
 (fun x y => x + y)
 (Nat.add_assoc).
```

This is more or less the approach automated in [Hierarchy Builder](https://github.com/math-comp/hierarchy-builder/), which you might want to look at for good practices regarding these kind of things.

Comment: Nice trick, but this way we lose the notation for record construction.

Comment: Indeed, although I would argue that you do not define new instances of algebraic structures all that often so it is not too bad. A possibility if you really want to regain the notation is to define a structure `pre_SG` with only the `oper` and `assoc` fields, and have `SG_builder {A : Type} (g : pre_SG A) : SG A`.